# noNamespaceSchemaLocation full directory path vs urn

Tags: magento2, xml

I'm trying to get into good habits off the bat with Magento 2. module development but I've come across something I can't find any writing on. Though this is probably as I'm unsure what to search for.

I've seen a lot of examples of Magento 2 modules with the following style syntax in their XML files

```
<config ... xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/App/etc/routes.xsd">
```

But I've been looking at the [Magento github sample modules](https://github.com/magento/magento2-samples) and they use the following style of noNamespaceSchemaLocation

```
<config ... xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:App/etc/routes.xsd">
```

Both work but the code from the github repo seems a lot cleaner. Is there a reason for the 2 available methods? if one better than the other?

Answer (score 3):

Urn locators was introduced to support modules in different locations. When module developed the code placed in app/code, but when you use composer the code placed in vendor directory. As result relative path will not work.